# Matlab axis throwing errors on negative limit values

Tags: matlab

I have this limit values (Max and Min) of x, y and z and i want to use this in axis.

when I do this, It gives error

```
xlim([-5037.287109375 -8527.0703125]);
ylim([1008.826171875 -1096.7156982421875]);
zlim([10.82118 -63.9398])
axis([xlim ylim zlim])

Limits must be a 2-element vector of increasing numeric values
```

but it works if i change all those negative values to positive

How do I fix this kind of problems.

Comment: Because the Limits must be a 2-element vector of increasing numeric values. Just make sure they are **increasing**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm, error tells you what is wrong - 2 element vector of increasing values. -8000 is smaller than -5000, only its absolute value is larger. So, at the very least, swap those values in all 3 vectors.

Comment: Thanks, that solve the issues. One more question. I have 2 frames and I want to plot both frames. While plotting both frames changes the position of their axis. Is it possibe to freeze those axis so that both frames can be plotted.